# How can I solve Valgrind Problem : "no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)"

Tags: c, valgrind

```
  #include <stdlib.h>

  void f(void)
  {
     int* x = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
     x[10] = 0;        // problem 1: heap block overrun
  }                    // problem 2: memory leak -- x not freed

  int main(void)
  {
     f();
     return 0;
  }
```

I'm just having a simple test about using Valgrind to seek memory leaks in the program

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

I executed like this

```
==22833== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22833== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22833== Using Valgrind-3.18.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22833== Command: ./a.out
==22833== 
--22833-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./a.out"
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
==22833== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2012c000, 0x80001ff2c000) (defined)
==22833== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff2012c000, 0x7fff7ff04000) (defined)
==22833== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fff8e3a8000, 0x7fffc012c000) (noaccess)
==22833== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffc012c000, 0x7fffe2ff0000) (defined)
==22833== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x7fffe2ff0000, 0x7fffffe00000) (noaccess)
==22833== 
==22833== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22833==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22833==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==22833== 
==22833== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22833== 
==22833== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==22833== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

and I got this result, but it seems that something is wrong due to "warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)". How should I handle it?

Comment: To build with debug information you need to add the `-g` flag. I also recommend you disable optimizations when building (`-O0`) as otherwise the compiler might not add code to actually call `f` (since it doesn't really do anything useful or have any kind of side-effect).

Comment: Add the -g option.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by using -g flag but still I'm struggling with detecting memory leak. "Warning: set address range perms: large range"  Is this problem affect my result?

Comment: If your output is the same as above after your recent change then that means `f()` was stripped out by the compiler as having no effect. (total heap use is zero)

Comment: Have you tried to build with `-O0` as well, to disable optimizations?

Comment: compiler might be smart enough to remove allocations of objects that are not visible outside the function. Disable all optimizations

Comment: If you allocate an array `x` of 10 integers, accessing `x[10] = 0;` is out of bounds.  Indexes start at 0 and go up to 9.  The code is simply wrong to attempt that assignment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think that't the point. To get some response from Valgrind that the code is indexing out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude — as you're aware (but the OP probably isn't) the function needs to be more like `int f(void) { int *x = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); x[0] = 37; x[1] = time(0); return x[1] % x[0]; }` (possibly with `x[10] = 0;` to provoke Valgrind) and using `printf("f() = %d\n", f());` in `main()`.  With `time()` in the mix, the compiler cannot eliminate the function.  (Of course, the code would need `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <time.h>` added too.). Or you could have `int main(void) { return f(); }` which avoids adding the standard I/O library.

Comment: macOS support in Valgrind is not great, and there may also be problems correctly redirecting functions like malloc.